# Mlflow model signature in R API

Tags: r, mlflow

Can somebody show how to specify inputs/outputs for `mlflow_log_model` (R API). Seems like it's `model_spec` param, but i'm not sure
For instance, let's take following columns:

```
input = c("international_plan","total_day_minutes","total_day_charge")
output="churn"

mlflow_log_model(model_glm,"churn-glm",
                 registered_model_name="churn-glm-model")
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I was trying the exact same for long and give up now. I do not think model signatures are implemented within the R API, as I do not find anything about it in https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/R-api.html. I think model_spec is not  referring to model signature. It is simply missing and after what I tried, I see that the support for R is fewer that for python.

Answer (score 0):

For input/output format You need to use `signature` field in MLModel configuration. According to mlflow documentation, You can pass `model_spec` parameter to `mlflow_log_model()` function; this parameter in turn is passed to `mlflow_save_model()` function. The param is documented as follows:

> `model_spec` - MLflow model config this model flavor is being added to

From MLModel documentation, the [configuration object has a field `signature` and it must be specified using JSON format](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#fields-in-the-mlmodel-format)

They provide some examples, so I would try something like this:

```
mlflow_log_model(
  model_glm,
  model_spec = list(
    inputs = '[{"name": "sepal length (cm)", "type": "double"}, {"name": "sepal width
      (cm)", "type": "double"}, {"name": "petal length (cm)", "type": "double"}, {"name":
      "petal width (cm)", "type": "double"}, {"name": "class", "type": "string", "optional": "true"}]',
    outputs = '[{"type": "integer"}]'
  )
)
```

I didn't test this.

---

I run some tests and it's not working as expected :( Model is not logged at all. I found no further documentation for that, so the question is open.